# Redux not working in a particularly Route after Refresh only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I am using React-Redux , React-Router , Saga , React-Thunk 
All my application works well , one component which also dispatch action to be rendered gives me an error whenever I refresh the page OR type the url myself its a component that renders only when a photo clicked it display the particular photo after dispatching and filtering the state by the id which I send in the url , It works fine when I click the photo but after one refresh the state returns an empty array to be rendered here is my code

```js
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchImages} from '../redux/actions/Actions';
const Photos = props => {
    useEffect(()=>{props.fetchRequestedPhoto()},[props.requestedPhoto.length])
    console.log(props.requestedPhoto)
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>( {
    requestedPhoto:state.images
})

const mapDispatchToProps = () =>( {
    fetchRequestedPhoto:()=>{return fetchImages()}
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Photos);
```

navigation.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router , Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomePage from '../components/home'
import Categories from '../components/categories'
import  Photos from '../components/photos.js'
import Category from '../components/category'
const Routes = () => {
   return(
       <Router>
       <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}></Route>
       <Route exact path='/categories' component={Categories }></Route>
       <Route  exact path='/category/:category_id' component={Category}></Route>
       <Route exact path='/photo/:photo_id' component={Photos}></Route>
       </Router>
   )
}
export default Routes;
```

Action.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GetCategories,GetImages } from './actionTypes'
export function fetchCategories() {
   var url = 'http://localhost:4000/all_categories';
   return (dispatch) => {
       return axios.get(url).then((res) => {
           dispatch({
               type: GetCategories,
               payload: res.data
           })
       })
   } 
}
export function fetchImages(){
   var url ='http://localhost:4000/all_images';
   return(dispatch) => {
       return axios.get(url).then((res)=>{
           dispatch({
               type:GetImages,
               payload:res.data
           })  
       })
   }
}
```

saga.js

```
import {takeEvery,delay,put} from 'redux-saga/effects'
import axios from 'axios';

function* getImagesAsync(){
   delay(4000)
   const response=axios.get('http://localhost:4000/all_images');
   const payloadImages = response;
   yield put({type: 'GetImagesSaga', payload:payloadImages});   
}
export function* watchFetchImages(){
   yield takeEvery("GetImages",getImagesAsync);
}
```

Reducer.js

```
import { GetCategories , GetImages } from "../redux/actions/actionTypes"
const initialState = {
   categories: [],
   images:[]
};
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
       case GetCategories:
           return {...state, categories:action.payload}
       case GetImages:
           return{...state,images:action.payload}
       default:
       return state;
   }
};
export default rootReducer;
```

Any one could help me with this??

Comment: Without seeing your reducer I would assume your reducer returns with the default state after you refresh the page.

Comment: @Peter I added reducer.js code please advise me what is right to do and why as I am new to redux

Comment: Please include your `fetchImages` action and reducer and react-router config, too.

Comment: @Peter I added them

Comment: Your reducer is still missing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually?rq=1 <-- did you see this? I am not sure but maybe it is related.

Comment: @Peter I think this is a different problem my component problem is that when it is refreshed or when I write the URL manually the     `console.log(props.requestedPhoto)`  in my component returns an empty array which means the action firing fails to fetch the server
 and this happens only after a refresh.

Comment: @Hazem did you find any solution? I'm also facing this problem